# To store JavaScript variable output into a PHP variable and to database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am able to get javascript variable output into php variable,but i am not able to store php variable value stored from javascript variable into database its storing the whole script for eg:

```
<script>document.write(answer)</script>
```

I tried on update to redirect on registration page but it remain static on the same page.

Here is my code :

```
if(isset($_GET['status'])) 
{
if($_GET['status']=="Rejected")
{
echo("<script type='text/javascript'> var answer = prompt('Please enter'); </script>");?>
<script>var a = document.write(answer);
window.location.href = window.location.href+'#reason='+answer;</script>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['reason']))
{
$reason=$_GET['reason'];
$approve="UPDATE approveleave SET status='Rejected',rejectreason='".$reason."' WHERE id='".$id."'";
$result2=mysql_query($approve,$con);
header("location:registration.php");
}
}
}   
?>
```

Any solution will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you have wrongly written js inside php

Comment: This code is a mess. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1255289

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass the data throught url you should use "?" character

your script

```
 window.location.href = window.location.href+'#reason='+answer;</script>
```

how it should be

```
window.location.href = window.location.href+'?reason='+answer;</script>
```

Reformating your code:

```
if(!empty($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] == "Rejected") {
        if(!empty($_GET['reason'])) {
            $reason = $_GET['reason'];
            $approve="UPDATE approveleave SET status='Rejected',rejectreason='".$reason."' WHERE id='".$id."'";
            $result2=mysql_query($approve,$con);
            header("location: /registration.php");
        } else {
          ?>
          <script type='text/javascript'> 
            var answer = prompt('Please enter'); 
            var a = document.write(answer);
            window.location.href = window.location.href+'?reason='+answer;
          </script>
          <?php
        }
}
```

Use `empty()` function to check if a array is empty or not.

Note:
The `isset()` is used to check if a variable is defined or not.

The best way to interact with database is PDO.
Don't use `mysql_query()` because it is deprecated in the newer versions of Php.
You can use mysqli instead.

Comment: i had tried using "?" character still got the same result.

Comment: i will reformat your code for good, but you need tho make sure that javascript will run in your browser without errors and make sure that the if statments are ok

Comment: Yes i will make sure that it gets run

Comment: i just made couple of changes

Comment: @ Neo Morina It worked the only issue is before redirect it shows the value without echo.

Comment: @ Neo Morina the code you gave first is working correctly only before redirect it shows the value which we enter any fix for it ?

Comment: you are writing your answer with 'var a = document.write(answer);'

Comment: Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
if(isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status']=="Rejected") 
{
?>
<script type='text/javascript'> var answer = prompt('Please enter');
</script>
<script>var a = document.write(answer);
    window.location.href = window.location.href+'&reason='+answer;
</script>
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['reason']))
    {
        $reason=$_GET['reason'];
        $approve="UPDATE approveleave SET status='Rejected',rejectreason='".$reason."' WHERE id='".$id."'";
        $result2=mysql_query($approve,$con) or die(mysql_error());
        echo "<script> window.location = 'registration.php';</script>";
    }
}   
?>
```

I have reformatted your code and rather than using `<a>` tag, you should use query `?` to pass variables and read with `$_GET[]` method.

We can not see if you have database connection done or not anywhere. So, I have also added `mysql_error()`, if there is any problem with mysql connection, you should see error.

Comment: Did you try above code? I am feeling like your problem was with mysql connection.

Comment: Using your code its still not able to redirect and get insert into database.

Comment: Can you please give the URL that you are trying with query param? Are you getting correct data being inserted to database?

Answer (score 0):

You code may be like this

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['status'])) 
{
     if($_GET['status']=="Rejected")
    {

            echo("<script type='text/javascript'> var answer = prompt('Please enter'); </script>");?>
        <script>var a = document.write(answer);
        window.location.href = window.location.href+'&reason='+answer;</script>

<?php if(isset($_GET['reason'])) {
                      $reason=$_GET['reason'];
                        $approve="UPDATE approveleave SET status='Rejected',rejectreason='".$reason."' WHERE id='".$id."'";
                        $result2=mysql_query($approve,$con);
                      header("location:registration.php");
                  }


    }
}   
?>
```

Comment: This code gives the undefine error for reason

Comment: I just update the code. can you please check ?